# Empty Django project with error: missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, django, macos, django-admin

I just started to learn Django, created first project using `django-admin startproject Returner` and got an error trying to run it:

[image]

How I can solve that?

Possibly, the problem is related to multiple version of software. I have Python2.7 with Django 1.11 and Python3.5 with Django 2.0.

But I have properly set command line aliases from `Python` to `Python3.5`, from `pip` to `pip3.5`, and from `django-admin` to `python /.../python3.5/.../django-admin.py`

And generated files have the comment:

> Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.3.

And this code:

```
import sys
print('Python:')
print(sys.version)

import django
print('\nDjango:')
print(django.VERSION)
```

Turns into:

> Python:
>   3.5.0b2 (v3.5.0b2:7a088af5615b, May 31 2015, 01:00:01) 
>   [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
>
> Django:
>   (2, 0, 3, 'final', 0)

---

#### Update

I have set up Virtual Environment, added an App to my Project, but still get the same error when try to `runserver` or `migrate`. I hope someone will help me to solve this terrible problem, because it breaks all the plans of project development.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the `python manage.py migrate` command?

Comment: It gets me the same error. Previously I tried to start Django project in Python 2.7, it ran well and carefully wrote that I should launch this command. So, migrations aren't the problem at all.

Comment: Did you try to use a virtualenv?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! No. I know about this thing, but have no experience of use. So, I will use  it if I won't have found any other opportunity. Obviously, the problem may and I think must be solved without such services.

Comment: you can't develop in python without a virtualenv and it's also easy to use

Comment: Yes, it's really easy to use! But though I have set up the environment with new Django downloaded, I still get the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trials I think that the cause of the problem was a bug of my Python 3.5 release. The method `get_models` of the `Apps` class has this decorator:

```
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
```

Maybe the Python 3.5 implementation of this decorator hides the arguments of the methods.

To solve the problem, I just installed and used Python 3.7.